# Graphql schema for add friends

Tags: graphql, prisma-graphql, graphql-mutation

Hi I want to create schema for friends functionality. Where logged in user can send friend request to registered users. I have 2 table users and relation and can be able to get own friends. Its working in redux and react with node mysql. But I don’t know how i can achieve the same in GraphQL. I am using GraphQL prisma now using GraphQL cli

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you learn about GraphQL here: https://graphql.org/learn/ and then about Prisma here: https://www.prisma.io/docs/

This will help you understand how to create a GraphQL Schema for your needs and how to use Prisma to abstract the database access

Comment: That was not answer i was expecting